# Javascript fails to hide some DIVs

Tags: javascript, html, field

I got the "New user form". There are three different clearence levels:

- client
- clientContact
- clientRepresentative

And there are some fields, like newMail, newPostalCode, etc.

Here is a code I am using to show an element:

```
function doShow(obj) {
                    document.getElementById(obj).style.display = '';
                }
```

And a code I am using to hide an element:

```
function doHide(obj) {
                    document.getElementById(obj).style.display = 'none';
                }
```

It works for small blocks of data. While creating an user, the clearence level is specified, if it is clientRepresentative the appropriate field is being shown. 
In example, client has only one e-mail adress, clientRepresentative has two e-mail addresses and clientContact has three.

But this **don't work!**.
If I choose client, there is one e-mail, just as planned, but if I choose clientContact and then switch to clientRepresentative the redundant field (e-mail3) is **not being hidden**.

I believe this is a JavaScript issue, please help me, since my anger level hits the ceiling.

edit:
I forgot to paste function used to show/hide the items.

```
 if (clearenceLevel != "Chose...") {
                        if (clearenceLevel == "client") {

                            doShow("newMail");
                            doHide("newMail2");
                            doHide("newMail3");
                            doShow("newNip");
                            doShow("newRegon");
                            doShow("newStreet");
                            doHide("newHeadquarters");
                            doShow("newAddress");
                            doShow("newPostalCode");
                            doShow("kptekst");
                            doShow("newCity");
                            doShow("newAccount");
                            doShow("newState");
                            doHide("newStatus");
                            doHide("newPassword");
                        } else if (clearenceLevel == "clientRepresentative") {

                            doShow("newMail");
                            doShow("newMail2");
                            doHide("newStatus");
                            doHide("newMail3");
                            doHide("newNip");
                            doHide("newRegon");
                            doHide("newStreet");
                            doHide("newHeadquarters");
                            doHide("newAddress");
                            doHide("newPostalCode");
                            doHide("newCity");
                            doHide("newAccount");
                            doHide("newState");
                            doHide("kptekst");
                            doShow("newPassword");

                        } else if (clearenceLevel == "clientContact") {

                            doShow("newMail");
                            doShow("newMail2");
                            doShow("newMail3");
                            doHide("newNip");
                            doHide("newRegon");
                            doHide("newStatus");
                            doHide("newStreet");
                            doHide("newHeadquarters");
                            doHide("newAddress");
                            doHide("newPostalCode");
                            doHide("newCity");
                            doHide("newAccount");
                            doHide("newState");
                            doHide("kptekst");
                            doHide("newPassword");
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: What are you passing in to doShow and doHide? It looks like it should be a string (the element id) but the argument is called "obj". If you did pass in a DOM element object, then the code wouldn't work.

Comment: Are you 100% sure every ID exists in the document only once?

Comment: You really need some appropriate tools for debugging these things, like Firebug (on Firefox) or Fiddler (IE).

Comment: Two possible problems:  
**1.** Did you debug it using Firebug for instance? Could it be that your *magic strings* have a typo?  
**2.** Event triggering: Check that your function that does all these showing and hiding actually does get called. Take the same approach: Debug it using Firebug.

Comment: The issue was with the doShow("newState"); 
Firebug has shown it crashes at this point since... there is no such field in my form! Thanks you very much guys, you made my day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question, but a suggestion on how you could improve the way that you're doing this. Instead of having to list each property to display and hide for each user level, do something like:

```
<input type="text" name="email" class="client representative contact">
<input type="text" name="ssn" class="representative">
```

Then when the user level changes hide *everything* and then unhide everything that has the correct level. So in my example "email" is available to "client" "representative" and "contact". So if they switched to any of those levels, this field would display, however "ssn" is only available to "representative" so it wouldn't display for anyone else.

The advantage of this would be the ability to easily add a brand new item *without* needing to modify the Javascript, only the HTML.

```
if (clearenceLevel != "Chose...") {
                    hideAll();
                    if (clearenceLevel == "client") {
                        doShow("client");
                    } else if (clearenceLevel == "clientRepresentative") {
                        doShow("representative");
                    } else if (clearenceLevel == "clientContact") {
                        doShow("contact");
                    }
 }
```

Comment: Great idea, I will adopt my code this way. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably made a mistake in the code.

else if (clearenceLevel == "clientRepresentative") {
doShow("newMail");
doShow("newMail2");
doHide("newStatus");
doShow("newMail3"); // shouldn't this be doHide()?
// etc

From your message I understood that you want to hide the e-mail3 while switching to clientRepresentative, but in the code above doShow() is executed instead of doHide().

Comment: You're right, it should be doHide(), but it doesn't change anything, because when clientRepresentative is chosen newMail3 field is STILL visible ;/
The funny thing is, if I chose clientRepresentative, and then client, redundant field is being hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, 
I am posting the form used to send the data

```
  echo '<div id="newMail"><br><font color="red">*</font>email: <input type="text" name="newMail" value="' . $_POST['newMail'] . '" /> </div>';
    echo '<div id="newMail2"><br>email 2: <input type="text" name="newMail2"  value="' . $_POST['newMail2'] . '" /> </div>';
    echo '<div id="newMail3"><br>email 3: <input type="text" name="newMail3"   value="' . $_POST['newMail3'] . '" /> </div>';
    echo '<div id="newNip"><br>nip: <input type="text" maxlength="15" name="newNip" value="' . $_GET['nip'] . '"/> </div>';
    echo '<div id="newRegon"><br>regon: <input type="text" name="newRegon"  value="' . $_POST['newRegon'] . '" /> </div>';
    echo '<div id="newStreet"><br>Street: <input type="text" name="newStreet" value="' . $_POST['newStreet'] . '" /> </div>';
    echo '<div id="newHeadquarters"><br>Headquarters: <select name="newHeadquarters"> ';
```

Comment: You are not closing your last div in this code.  Is that a SO typo or an oversight?

Comment: It is just an oversight, I was hiding the field which doesn't existed. And the Javascript code was crashing. Thanks for your effort.